# Save and get hash from sql

Tags: php, mysql

first I create a hash code and save it in my database:

```html
$key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE my_table SET md5key = MD5('$key') WHERE id = 1");
```

But the $key does not match the code in the database?

$key = e114e5bd4c8551d4e46a636d0c087b0e
database = c00855d30f0c2c2f527b95f8be86a8b3

My field in the database has the following option:

md5key  varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You compute md5 twice, first in PHP then in MySQL, is that intentional

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because your $key variable has an MD5 hash already, but when you make the update query, you use a MD5 function again, so the value inserted in the database will be different.

Just do this:

```
$key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE my_table SET md5key = '$key' WHERE id = 1");
```